# Pass the variables from python script to shell script when python script is being called inside shell script

Tags: python, shell, variables, subprocess

I have a shell script test.sh and it calls a python script test.py. This python file generates a variable like list type. How do I pass the list variable from python to outside shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I just include the python directly in the bash script.

```sh
test=`python -c "print('Hello world!')"`
echo $test
```

If you want to run a program just have your program print the final value and assign that output to a variable. So let's say you have `test.py` . . .

```py
print('Hello world!')
```

and `test.sh`

```sh
test=`python test.py`
echo $test
```